# debian wheezy extreme boot delay

Tags: debian, systemd, udev

I migrated from Arch to Debian(wheezy) recently.

Since Debian was still using sysVinit, I migrated to systemd, but following [this.](https://wiki.debian.org/systemd)

The system booted after a long init, using fallback LSB scripts for some services.

I initially started analyzing boot using `systemd-analyze blame | plot`.
It seems that after `console-setup` unit start, there was a pause for about 1 minute.

I setup `bootchart2` which indicated a rather long running `udevd` process which which finally leads to `sysinit.target` at which point remaining units to fireup unto `graphical.target`.

I also have migrated manually some LSB scripts to systemd units, currently have just a bare minimum only in `/etc/rcS.d` for bootup.

Still there has been no change in the boot characteristics.

I don't know what else to look into further.
Except I noticed this in `dmesg`, which seems like a huge gap, seeming to suggest that keyboard init is delaying the udev job, or am I just being optimistic.

```
[   15.423975] cfg80211:     (57240000 KHz - 63720000 KHz @ 2160000 KHz), (N/A, 0 mBm)
[   97.812894] input: ACPI Virtual Keyboard Device as /devices/virtual/input/input6
```

In any case I am not able to debug any further.

Please help in suggesting how to resolve the slow boot up with systemd.

NOTE: with initialy complete sysv type boot, I got the graphical(`gdm3`) prompt in about 30s, which is consistent with what I used top get in Arch.